# Move element created to textarea

Tags: javascript

I would like to link the 2 scripts to send the result of the first to the clipboard, using the second script. Both work but separately
Thank you, sorry if I am not clear.

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Click the button to create a h1 element with some text.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var h = document.createElement("H1");
var t = document.createTextNode("It works");
h.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(h);
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js">
</script>

<textarea name="box-content" id="box-content" rows="10" cols="70">
Will be copied to clipboard.
Line2.
Line3.
</textarea>

<br /><br />
```

Comment: You can not add tags in `textarea`, try `<div contenteditable="true"></div>` if I have got you right!

Comment: @RayonDabre what do you mean by "You can not add tags in textarea"? see this http://jsfiddle.net/mrqoj75c/

Comment: @caramba, will they be rendered as HTML elements ? What OP is trying to achieve is to have `heading` element in `textarea` and this is what I meant.In your example, browser is treating `tag` as `string` not `HTML element` !

Comment: @RayonDabre I see. Now your comment makes more sense to me. I didn't decipher the  ` . . . place the output (result) . . . ` like that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply by changing `.value` of textarea:

```
 document.getElementById('box-content').value = "It works";
```

Comment: @RayonDabre As you see it's not full function. Also he creates `<h1>`, appends text and than appends `<h1>` to body. Now taking off text append `<h1>` will be not visible (I assume it's just as placeholder for text)

Answer (score 0):

You can not place a `tag` in `textArea` tag.

*The `<textarea>` tag defines a multi-line text input control.A text area can hold an unlimited number of characters, and the text renders in a fixed-width font (usually Courier).The size of a text area can be specified by the cols and rows attributes, or even better; through CSS' height and width properties.*
[HTML textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

Instead you can place text only in `areatag`.

```js
function myFunction() {
    //var h = document.createElement("H1");
    var t = document.createTextNode("It works");
    //h.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById('box-content').appendChild(t);
}
myFunction();
```

```html
<textarea name="box-content" id="box-content" rows="10" cols="70"></textarea>
```